# Why do I got php code when accessing phpmyadmin?

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use phpymadmin on Ubuntu 22.04, I've already install LAMP server. When I accesss `localhost/phpmyadmin` on my browser, I get the following php code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4TQz.png)

I know there's other question similar to this, but so far I haven't found a solution. I've already installed phpmyadmin and apache. I've aleready install `libapache2-mod-php8.2`, and also tried creating a symbolic link to phpMyAdmin `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`.
What can I do to solve this? Thanks, I'm still new to ubuntu

Comment: Did you *enable* the PHP module?  `sudo a2enmod php8.2` needs to be *manually* enabled and then you have to restart Apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`.  If this works I"ll write it as an answer

Comment: @ThomasWard , yes I've enable php module

Answer (score 0):

The same problem ocurred to me today after upgrading to the newest Ubuntu version. All the required packages were installed and the symbolic link was working.

I got it back working by removing (`apt-get purge phpmyadmin`) the PHPMyAdmin package via the package installer and, instead, installing PHPMyAdmin via the **official .zip** from the software page. (https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).